# Proving compactness in $\mathsf{ZF}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider a family $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ of disjoint sets. Let $X$ be the union of all $A_i$, and equip it with the smallest topology $\tau$ making the $A_i$ closed in $X$. How can one prove in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $(X,\tau)$ is compact?

One may apply the Alexander subbase theorem when working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but the theorem's proof is based on some form of choice.

---

This is part of an exercise in "The Axiom of Choice" by T. Jech, where the goal is to prove that the Axiom of Choice follows from the following assertion: If $(X,\tau)$ is a compact space and $I$ is an arbitrary index set, then $\prod_{i\in I} X$ equipped with the product topology is also compact.

Comment: [Here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/01.pdf) is another short proof that Tychonoff implies full AC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, though the assertion above is not exactly Tychonoff (yes, they are equivalent, but it needs to be proven).

Comment: Yes Tychonoff for powers $X^I$, as you use, is equivalent to Tychonoff for arbitrary families. It sort of follows from all this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to look at subbase, because we have a neat description of all open subsets. A subset $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $U=X$ or $U=\emptyset$ or $X\backslash U$ is a finite union of some $A_i$-s. You can verify that this is a topology and the smallest topology having $A_i$ as closed subsets. I don't think there's any choice involved here.

Assume a family $\mathcal{U}$ covers $X$. Take a single subset $U\in\mathcal{U}$. It follows that there are at most finitely many $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ not covered by $U$. But each $A_i$ is covered by some $U_i\in\mathcal{U}$. And so $\{U,U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ is a finite subcovering of $\mathcal{U}$. Here we only utilize the finite choice, no additional axioms required.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest topology that makes each $A_i$ closed is essentially the following: give $I$ the co-finite topology, then replace $i$ by $A_i$.

It is easy to see why the co-finite topology is compact, even in $\sf ZF$. Given any non-empty open set, then only finitely many points are missing from it, so any cover has a finite subcover: pick some non-empty open set in the cover, then finitely many more are all you need to cover the missing points.

The fact that we replace each $i$ with $A_i$ with completely irrelevant here, since the restriction of the topology to each $A_i$ is indiscrete.